# npm requires a peer of a lower version than installed version

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to use amexio-ng-extensions@3.2.2 from https://amexio.tech/ and when I install, npm tells me:

```
npm WARN amexio-ng-extensions@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

In my `package.json` I have an Angular 5.2.0 dependency:

```
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0"
```

Is it possible to use *amexio* with an installed version higher than required?

And, in general, is it safe to run a new application with an Angular lower than available, because of peer dependency?

This scenario means that I will be stuck with the version of Angular imposed by amexio in the future?

Comment: You need to use "@angular/core": "^5.0.0" in package.json file.

Comment: So, in your opinion, if I choose amexio, I must opt-in to it (in this case, but this may apply for other libraries too) and lose the chance to upgrade angular when needed?

Comment: were you able to solve this, i am facing a similar issue where i have @angular/cdk of 11 but for ng-pick-datetime it is asking me to have a dependency of ^7.0.0 -_-